# optaplanner: modeling simple preemptive scheduling

Tags: job-scheduling, optaplanner

I'm new to optaplanner but I have a modest experience with scheduling algorithm. I'm trying to implement a very simple algorithm that is capable of resolving a particular scheduling problem I have and I want to do it with optaplanner. Yes, there is an example of job shop scheduling but its model isn't described in the doc and what I need is quite different.

In short, I have multiple project each of which has a single jobs that need to be executed among a pool of equals resources respecting some time windows restriction: eg. each resource is available for a specific job only inside its time window.

My model would look like this:

- Job class with the following properties
- int minDuration, it represent the minimal duration of the job on all the resources inside the time window. It is an hard constraint
- TimeInterval timeWindow, the time window in which I have to process the job for at least minDuration
- List< TimeInterval> effectiveProcessing. This could be the decision variable, because change during processing, a time interval is just a couple of start time and stop time.
- Map< Resource, List< TimeInterval>> resourceAvailability. This is a problem constraint (hard). It tells, for each job, when the specific resource is available.

The score calculation should be simple, but I need some hint for the rest of the algorithm and some suggestion by experts. Do I need some additional code to build those intervals?
What do you think about my model? I need to build something that just works, then I will worry about optimization.
Any help is much appreciated!

edit:
alternative model:
each job represent an operation on a resource in its availability slot, so we have several job, one for each availability slot on a resource. Imagine like a greedy initial allocation in which each job use all the resources available always. The planning variable is a priority integer that vary in a finite range. This priority determine the way a job gain access to a resource (higher priority goes first). The solution imply calculating time slots according to the priority, the score is problem dependent. Let's see if it works.

Comment: How is this problem *quite different* from the [Project Job Scheduling example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c)? The only difference I see is the time window restriction.

Comment: The question is hard for me to parse. Would you mind summarizing it more and - even better - draw [a class diagram like this](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/images/Chapter-Use_cases_and_examples/curriculumCourseClassDiagram.png)?

Comment: there is no job precedence and there is preemption, a job can be interrupted and restarted later. Usually this kind of problem are resolved giving priority to jobs, so when a job is released with a higher priority, the running job get interrupted and the new one start. 
As I said, my current model use this priority as a planning variable, then compute the schedule and calculate a score on that.

I'm also evaluating the possibility to add an additional chained variable to build an ordered list of jobs and help me computing the schedule.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I am trying to implement a job shop but struggling. My planning entity is an operation (it has an id, a duration and an assigned resource). Each resource has a calendar (e.g [0,1,1,0,..] say that the resource is not available in the first period, available in the next two periods and then not available again). The aim is to fix a starting date for each operation such that the resource is available. I am trying to implement the constraint "a resource cannot work on the same operation at same time". The problem is I am having only a starting time as a variable. Any idea?

Comment: Try asking a new question, please don't mix it in with an existing one if it's not the same question.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I apologize, I posted here because I reached my limit to ask questions. I can' post a question for now.